# Configure a public site in AEM (CQ5)

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, publish, aem

**Current Behavior**

I have a Publish Node at "http://pubXX.correlate.net/", when I hit this particular URL it prompts me to log in. Once I log in it takes me to "http://pubXX.correlate.net/projects.html"

As a admin I can see a Site ("Geometrixx Outdoor Site") available to me and I can view the Site at "http://pubXX.correlate.net/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.html"

**Future Behavior Required**

I need to configure the Publish Node such that any user who requests for "http://pubXX.correlate.net/" is directly taken to the "Geometrixx Outdoor Site" either after or prior to log in prompt. If it is not possible to configure it this way, please point out the closest possible solution to this.

I am new to AEM and CQ hence I am not aware of the configuration scenarios, excuse me if I have missed out other critical details required to analyse the problem (if so please point that to me and I will provide the same).

Hoping to get a quick response, and I thank all for their help.

Comment: I would verify that your instance is actually running in "publish" mode. It sounds like it's behaving as an author.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the quickstart documentation http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/getting_started/download_and_startworking.html to confirm that you set this up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Note before: Please make sure your runmode is Publish. You can check:
/system/console/config -> Tab 'Sling Settings'

*See more info how to set: http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/RunModeSetUp.html*

I see two challenges:

**Redirect toplevel domain**

The page should be forwarded directly from your top-level domain to a specific page. This can be done by configuring a slingmapping which forwards the page right page on request.

*See more info: http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html*

**Login**

For a login you can configure the Closed User Groups (CUG) mechanism. With configuring this you can force a user to login for a specific part of your site-tree. This configuration can be set on the pageproperties (tab advanced). On this tab you can configure the allowed usergroups and the login page. When the user reaches a site which is part of the CUG (page self or childeren), AEM will forward he user to the login page. After login the user will be redirected back to the referer page.

On the out-of-the-box login component you can configure a success page in case the user lands directly on the loginpage (no referer).

*See more info: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/create_apply_cug.html*